# How do I find the best Activity Tracker for my needs?

Tags: tracking, app

## N.B This is an attempt at a [good shopping question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Please provide feedback in the comments rather than voting to close straight away.

I've seen a lot of 'Top 10' lists, as well as amazon reviews, and I've looked over the questions in [tracking](/questions/tagged/tracking) and [app](/questions/tagged/app), but I've yet to come across a useful website or tool for figuring out which Activity tracker is best suited to me?

The closest I've found is [this one](https://www.dcrainmaker.com/2016/11/winter-sports-recommendations.html#dont-forget-the-comparison-tool), but it lacks details like sleep tracking and other 'features' (app compatibility, HR monitor, VO2 etc.) I feel I'd want in an activity tracker.

Is there a tool like this?

Comment: The reason you haven't found a web site or tool is that any response would need to be totally subjective to your needs.  It's tough to quantify "best suited for me".

Comment: @rrirower I disagree,  this is the basis of the blog I posted. It would have a list of current activity trackers and their features. You could then filter out the ones that don't meet your needs.

Comment: @Pureferret - Honestly, I've known DC for a bit from some triathlon boards, and his site is about the most complete you'll find. There is no tool/website that I'm aware of that you plug in your wants and it spits out a recommendation. If it's not on rainmaker, doubt it's anywhere.

Comment: @JohnP that would make a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that you are going to find a better resource than you have already noted in your answer, for DC Rainmakers blog. His site is fairly comprehensive and non partisan (i.e. he doesn't make money from the manufacturers for ads or shill evaluations). If you don't find it on his site, you probably aren't going to find it. I personally am not aware of any site where you put in your "desired features" and it spits out models.

What you can do, is work from the rarest feature that you want (i.e. the feature that is on the fewest activity trackers), and that gets you your narrowest list. From there, you can check the other features of the tracker, and see which one(s) come the closest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Garmin's Vivosmart HR band. HR monitor is very accurate. Steps are calculated a bit silly, as well as floors. Looks like band is prepared for runners, so if you spend more time at the gym - there are better options. I know, there is new version of this band, with VO2 metering, but that is quite questionable to me. They have all the data somewhere in the cloud, so I can see what they show.

I'll look for something with Android, or Tizen - or better to say - system that can be extended. I can do that for my own, but also I can use software provided by others. That way, I can better track different aspects of my training - like breaks between sets. Also I can have that data for my own.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am however not looking for recommendations but for places that allow me to compare activity trackers for myself.

Comment: Garmin has an app. There are weekly challenges, you can have friends and compare steps, and perhaps other aspects of training. Before that Vivosmart v2, I had Mio band... Garmin's app is much better.

Answer (score -1):

I have had Fitbit before. Then I got a Microsoft Band 2 and I feel that it is much better in terms of hardware, software, data, and data visualization. Too bad they don't make it anymore but this fitness tracker is excellent. If it is not on your list at least check it out there is so much it can do compared to other fitness trackers.

On the negatives side its software is currently missing calorie intake tracking.